# Convert set of amplitudes into Audio file

Tags: javascript, html, audio, waveform

I have a set of amplitudes in a javascript array

```
var amplitude=[1,2,3,4,5,6,8,9,4,3,1,6,2,6,3,3,1,5,8,87,11,2,43,54,64,63]
```

How to convert/dump this array of amplitude into an audio file(Eg. WAV/mp3 file)?

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
        <title id='title'>HTML Page setup Tutorial</title> 
        <script src='riffwave.js'></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">

          function myFunction() {
             var data = []; // just an array
             for (var i=0; i<10000; i++) data[i] = /*Math.round(255 * Math.random())*/i; // fill data with random samples
             var wave = new RIFFWAVE(data); // create the wave file
             var audio = new Audio(wave.dataURI); // create the HTML5 audio element
             audio.play();
          }
        </script>
    </head>
<body>

<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Click Me!</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try something, and then come back if you get stuck.

Comment: @evolutionxbox where to start from...i have no idea about this..

Comment: Have you searched Google for creating MP3 files using JS?

Comment: Yeah i got this http://js.do/blog/sound-waves-with-javascript/ but couldn't get code for this

Comment: check the link [https://processing.org/tutorials/sound/](https://processing.org/tutorials/sound/)

Comment: @Rishaldevsingh could you please explain the logic used in your link?

Comment: @PrateekRatnaker it will guide you through processing and details about sounds and amplitude and other important fields, have u gone through that?

Comment: @evolutionxbox i have created a riffwave which will be played on button click...now how to save this to a wav/audio file?